Hollywood movie about an Egypt pyramid worker freeing people
I saw this movie on one TV channel few months ago. This movie is based on history, or story. I'll describe a few scenes I remember:
In this movie, it shows that one king of Egypt has two sons, one is his own son and the other is adopted. As per a prophecy, he who saves the life of Egypt's prince will become king of Egypt. But both brothers don't believe in this and after this they go to war. There the prince's life is saved by the adopted son.
After the king's death, his son becomes king, and the adopted son goes to visit the kingdom. There in an area with pyramid workers, one old man tells him that "you are the man who will give freedom to us, and you are also the son of a worker".
After this he goes back to the kingdom and gets the right information. To save the kingdom, he leaves Egypt and goes to a stranger place. At the stranger place where shepherds live he marries a shepherd girl. That area has so many hills and one day he goes to one restricted hill and he meets God in the form of a little child, he's also injured on that hill. After this, as per the child's suggestions, he goes to Egypt to release their people (the workers and labors).
There with the help of God, he forces the king to release the workers on different terms like heavy rain, shortage of food, disease etc. At last he orders all workers to kill goats and color their doors with goat blood. All workers do the same, and at that night one dark shadow comes and kills all children whose door is not colored with goat blood. The king of Egypt's son also dies. 
At last the king orders to give freedom to the workers and they leave Egypt; after this, the king decides to go to war with the workers and they run to fight them. While on the other side the workers reach the sea, they inform that king and his army following them that they will kill them. Next morning, God splits the sea in the middle so all the workers cross the sea. When they all cross, the sea becomes full of water again, then all the army is destroyed and at last the king also dies in the water.
At last that person comes with all the workers to the shepherds' place, there they stay and in the last scene, that person becomes old and still goes for a journey, and there he also finds God in child form with him.

I find it hard to believe that you couldn't find the movie yourself with so much information.

Zikato, I forget name of movies.. Generally I saw one or two movies  per day, I show more than 2000+ movies.. so it little hard for me remember all movies name..

I can understand that. But I personally would google something like: "god parting sea"  -> you would get Moses > google "Moses films/ movies" > and you get a list of tops 8 movies. Then it's not hard to look at pictures, etc. Seems to me that 3 google queries are faster than writing 7 paragraphs long plot.

Do you really never heard of Moses? Where are you from? In the West even atheists know it. Not meaning to be rude, just curious.

Zikato while typing this plot I was at traveling so I have time.. And I forgot all movie name, when I start typing than turn by turn seen live in mind and just typing..

You're describing the story of Moses and you're likely after Ridley Scott's Exodus: Gods and Kings with Christian Bale from 2014.

It is the time of the Pharaohs, where Egyptians lived well, and there Jewish slaves were tormented. A guy rules all of Egypt with his two sons, Ramses his real son, and Moses his adopted son. The Pharaoh King wants to pick the new ruler of Egypt due to his bad health. Ramses became king and finds out his brother was born a Jew. Moses tries to find himself and tries helping his true people. Two brothers now compete for Egypt, one brother born to rule, and another brother born to oppose the rules and lead his people to glory. 

It starts with the prophecy you've mentioned and the rest is in there too. Here's the trailer:




But if it was animated, it would be Prince of Egypt.

Prince of Egypt's version of the story is a little different than what the OP described, though.

To be fair, the question originally said it's like it's based on history or something (I heavily proofed it).

There are several film adaptions of this biblic story. Exodus in Walts answer is the most actual release. Because you dont provided information of how old the movie was you saw, it is difficult to decide which adaption you mean.
The most famous version is The Ten Commandments from 1956 with Charlton Heston and Yul Brunner.
A (incomplete) list of movies about the Moses Story you can find here on wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_the_Bible#Moses_and_Israel_in_the_desert

True, but each version varies greatly. The OP's plot description is very detailed and the plot of Scott's Exodus fits it perfectly. The OP also said they saw it last year and I assumed they meant it was recent.

@walt: Yes, Exodus would fit the plot. But i just wanted to provide him some additional information. He said he watched it a year ago in tv, but Exodus was released about christmas in cinema last year,  i dont think it was already in tv about a year ago, so i wanted to provide him some extra information about older movies which could also fit the plot. Maybe he was just wrong with the time information. I did not see Exodus or all movies of the wiki-list, but i saw ten commandments and would say it also fits the plot.

In India, some movies broadcast in local T.V channel after 2 to 7 days from date of release that movie.. And good things for me is that, with the help of high speed internet i can download that movies in few minute..
